# Get cookie from another application in an angular application

Tags: angular, session-cookies, httpcookie

Is it possible to get a cookie stored by other application when the user clicked an hyperlink with target to the angular application?
java application ---> angular application
both application are running in the same server(tomcat) and port(8080)

I tried to use ngx-cookie-service but with no success

Comment: Given the applications are running on the same port, I'm also assuming you mean they're running on the same domain, it means you can only get the cookie in angular-land if it's not an httponly cookie. Is it an httponly cookie? Why do you (think you) need the cookie in the angular application? The browser (angular application) will send the cookie to the server anyway without you needing to access it in angular code, as long as it's on the same domain.

Comment: For the user the angular app is part of the java application(main), so whan I want is implement security access to angular app. When the user is not logged in the java app, angular app should be inaccessible also and redirect to the main url from java app.

Comment: To confirm - are the apps served on the same domain or different domains?

Comment: sure, both are in the same domain but different path

Comment: They need to be set to the same top level path - `/` - to be shared amongst both all applications on the same domain. Once you’ve done this, the browser does the rest